# Can I Make A Wireless button that tp's someone in Minecraft 1.13-1.14?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible for me to create a button that tp's someone without and redstone or commandblock on it or near the button like a wireless button

Comment: please dont post answers to reply to other people. use the [edit] button

Comment: What have you already tried? Arqade works better when you contribute your past trials. This will allow us to set a starting point that we can work from.

Answer (score 0):

no, but you can make something wireless, step 1: place a repeater somewhere (have it set to always active) then type into it

```
testforblock ~~1 ~~~1 [destination: x y z]
```

then put a choice block on top of it (if you were to do and item frame (or button) it would be like this: [image]

otherwise just put some block there then make sure the player themselves has to place that exact block at the coordinates, with the button it will only work when it's turned off (by turning itself off after being pressed because that's what they do automatically) then have whatever command you want to have run next in a command block at the side of the repeating command block (note: there has to be a redstone comparator between the repeating command block ((comparator needs to be facing the command block)) and the command block like in the image above, I'll post a vid on YouTube to further explain so you get a better understanding, I'll call it, "Placing A Block To Create A Wireless Activation (Command Block Tutorial)"....